# How do I login with javascript but store userinfo with php/mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I have created a javascript based login for my latest application, and everything works fine. The problem is that i want to store all users in a database, and dont know how to do this the facebook way. I have very good php and sql knowledge, so that is not a problem. I just need some advice on how to securely store the data.

The procedure i want is this:

User login with javascript popup -> check if facebook id exists in mysql table. if not, save with additional info -> user is logged in

Comment: You must be passing the PHP script some variables to determine if the user's in the DB or not, so why not just use those variables if you need to insert a new user?

Comment: The idea that i've got in my head (and haven't managed to implement) is to pass the facebook id + some hash for security reasons via ajax, and then get all the other facebook information on the php side. It's the security part that i need help with.

Comment: Security in what sense? Or: What exactly to do want to protect from a malicious user?

Comment: is there any reason that you cant just use the [FB.getLoginStatus()](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/) as your authentication?

Comment: 1. How can i create a safe hash to send with the ajax request? I need to make sure that the FBID in the querystring actually belongs to the current user. 2. Can i access that users fb info with the php sdk, or is some additional step required?

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId: 'YOUR_APP_ID',
        status: true,
        cookie: true,
        oauth: true
    });
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
        // response returns a JSON object containing data relevant to the logged in user.
        userID = response.authResponse.userID;

        // using jQuery to perform AJAX POST.
        $.post('form_handler.php', {userID: userID}, function() {
            // POST callback
        });
    });
}
</script>
```

Your form_handler.php file would need to be set up to fetch the userID variable from $_POST. From there you can use SQL to check if the user already exists, etc.

If your concern is that the userID JavaScript variable can be easily tampered with, I suggest using the PHP SDK within the form_handler.php file to grab the current uid. Inside of form_handler.php here (in the most basic form) is what you would need to do:

```
<?php
require('facebook.php');
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => YOUR_APP_ID,
    'secret' => YOUR_APP_SECRET
));
// get the current logged in userID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

// SQL queries (check if user exists, insert, etc.)

?>
```

The above code assumes you've migrated your app to oAuth 2.0.

Comment: @kongaraju Yes, the $ is a shortcut for jQuery.  So in that example, he could have also written jQuery.post('form_handler.php, ..

Answer (score -1):

After a successful login with Facebook JS Login call this function **testAPI()**

**yourJSfile.js**

```
function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {

        var json = JSON.stringify(response);
        setCookie("fbresponse_"+response.id, json, 1);
        facebook_response = response;
        doLocalPosiive();
        return;
        for(var propt in response){
            console.log(propt + ': ' + response[propt]);
        }
    });
}

function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{
    var exdate=new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value=encodeURIComponent(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}
```

The testAPI function will convert the response to JSON string and save it to cookie and on your php page you can retrieve the cookie and parse the signed_request ( and verify the signed request with your valid app_secret which is known to you alone I guess) and decode the JSONed Response, then do whatever you want with it safely in your php/mySQL.

**thePHPfile.php**

```
<?php

function getSignedRequest($app_id){
    $signed_request = $_COOKIE["fbsr_{$app_id}"];
    if($signed_request){
        return $signed_request;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

function parseSignedRequest($signed_request, $secret){
    list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2);

    //Decode the data
    $sig = base64_url_decode($encoded_sig);
    $data = json_decode(base64_url_decode($payload), true);

    if(strtoupper($data['algorithm']) !== 'HMAC-SHA256'){
        error_log("Unknown Algorithm. Expected HMAC-SHA256");
        return null;
    }

    //Verify the signed_resquest
    $expeted_sig = hash_hmac('sha256', $payload, $secret, $raw = true);
    if($sig !== $expeted_sig){
        error_log("Bad Signed JSON signature!");
        return null;
    }

    return $data;
}

function base64_url_decode($str){
    //$str .= str_repeat("=", (4-(strlen($str)%4)));
    return base64_decode(strtr($str, '-_', '+/')); 
}

// Please edit the next 2 lines
$app_id = "314xxxxxxxxx990";
$app_secret = "56b5eaxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx37c799";



if($fbsr = getSignedRequest($app_id)){
    $response = parseSignedRequest($fbsr, $app_secret);
    if($response['user_id']){
        $js_response = $_COOKIE["fbresponse_{$response['user_id']}"];       
        $response_array = (json_decode($js_response, true));

        //you can perform your database activities here now
    }
}

?>
```

Please don't forget to edit your **APP_ID** and **APP_SECRET**. 
I hope you or someone else find this useful.

Comment: This is the technique I used in my recent project and it works fine.